# short not being printed correctly c++

Tags: c++, integer, printf, short

I have this list definition in c++

```
short list[] = {(short)0x32, (short)0x0F, (short)0xFFFF, (short)0x2A};
```

And I'm getting this print using prinf:

```
32 F FFFFFFFF 2A
32 F FFFFFFFF 2A
```

But when I use different numbers I get the espected result.

```
short list[] = {(short)0x32, (short)0x0F, (short)0x7FFF, (short)0x2A};

32 F 7FFF 2A
32 F 7FFF 2A
```

I'd like to know what's happening.
Why is it printing a full integer in the frist place?
Thanks.

Comment: And *how* do you print it? With what format specifier? Perhaps [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might help you see what specifier should be used for `short` (because I'm guessing you're not using the correct modifier for `"%d"`).

Comment: Using `%d` format for a `short` gives undefined behaviour.   Use `%hd` instead.

Comment: @Peter: no, `%d` is fine with `printf` and a `short` (apart from a possible annoyance with sign extension, which we see here) - you may be thinking of `scanf` ?

Comment: There's an error in my previous comment, I meant that you use `"%X"` without any size modifier (not `"%d"` as I wrote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are printing the numbers with `printf("%X", value)`.

In that case you are most likely irritated by sign-extension. The short value `0xFFFF` which you have specified equals the decimal value `-1`. If this is extended/casted to a 32bit integer value you will get the same `-1` value, but it's binary representation is `0xFFFFFFFF`. This is what you see that gets printed. If you print with `printf("%hX", value)` you should see the correct value, if you don't have another cast from short to int in between.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the explanation. Yep, I was using %X directly